# How to perform functions to a newly added column in a spark data frame using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I was trying to create a new column in pyspark using literals but when I am trying to do some functions using that column, it shows error like this
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'show'`
my code is

```
autodata1=autodata.withColumn('pricePerMPG',(col('PRICE')/(col('MPG-CITY')+col('MPG-HWY')/2))).show(truncate=False)`
autodata1.show()
from pyspark.sql.functions import max
max = autodata1.agg({"pricePerMPG": "max"}).collect()[0]
print(max)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: `autodata1=autodata.withColumn('pricePerMPG',(col('PRICE')/(col('MPG-CITY')+col('MPG-HWY')/2))).show(truncate=False)` Remove the show here. It returns a None object.

Comment: Check whether your data contains value as 0 for the column `MPG-CITY` and `MPG-HWY` in any case if they are of numeric type. Also, kindly edit your question rather than posting changes in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
autodata1=autodata.withColumn('pricePerMPG',(col('PRICE')/(col('MPG-CITY')+col('MPG-HWY')/2))).show(truncate=False)`
```

Here your `autodata` is a dataframe but when you add show at the last of this then it will returns unit that's why your `autodata1` is not a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Your `show()` trigger a action and returna Non object.

```
autodata1=autodata.withColumn('pricePerMPG',(col('PRICE')/(col('MPG-CITY')+col('MPG-HWY')/2)))
autodata1.show(truncate=False)
from pyspark.sql.functions import max
max = autodata1.agg({"pricePerMPG": "max"}).collect()[0]
print(max)
```